# Find out the count of sign up users according to monthly basis?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing the query which will give the count of signup users on monthly basis.How much Signup is done in particular month.The month will be sort in Ascending order from January to December.Please help me to resolve this issue.The month should be in Words instead of number.My approach is given below:-

```
User.aggregate([{
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date("2016-01-01")
      } 
    } 
  }, { 
    $group: {
      _id: { 

        "month": { "$month": "$createdAt" },

      },
      count:{$sum: 1}
    }
  },{"$sort": {"createdAt": 1}}]).exec(function(err,data){
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error Fetching model');
      res.status(500).send();
    } else {
      res.send(data);
    }
  });
```

Actual Output:-

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 4
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 5
    },
    "count" : 8.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 2
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "month" : 3
    },
    "count" : 1.0
}
```

//Expected Output

```
 {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : "February"
        },
        "count" : 1.0
    }


    {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : "March"
        },
        "count" : 1.0
    }

    {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : "April"
        },
        "count" : 1.0
    }

    {
        "_id" : {
            "month" : "May"
        },
        "count" : 8.0
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good use-case for [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // your aggregation stages
    {
        $addFields: {
            "_id.month": {
                $switch: {
                    branches: [
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$_id.month", 1 ] }, then: "January" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$_id.month", 2 ] }, then: "February" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$_id.month", 3 ] }, then: "March" },
                        { case: { $eq: [ "$_id.month", 4 ] }, then: "April" }
                        // ...
                    ],
                    default: "December"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w_Hg3Mf0QHD)